# chrome autofills wrong information on a website

Tags: login, html, forms

on this website

https://members.zipcar.co.uk/register/

Chrome autofills the username field with my email address

(i'm not talking about automatic suggestion in a popup, I mean it just puts the value in)

[image]

But the value of that field  should not be an email address, it should be  just bla, not blah@gmail.com

When I double click it I notice there is only one suggestion of blah@gmail.com

what is causing this - e.g. if there is some website whose text field has the sane name, then is there a way to find out what that website is?  And can chrome not distinguish between websites? And even then, why would Chrome not be saving the username of bla even when I type it in and am able to log in?

I've tried it with and without the 'keep me logged in' checked, and it makes no difference.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome tries to intelligently fill in the boxes using your browsing history. It generally reads the code and searches for matching patterns. You probably used another site where some "similar" key words are used (for e.g., the website maker may designate username as uname on two sites, then Chrome recognizes it to be the same, even when the username for one is your email and for the other is your phone). This website probably calls this field "email" or something similar where you usually login, which could be the reason why Chrome is so adamant on it.

Try simply logging in for a few more days, then Chrome would start suggesting the proper login. If it doesn't, I add it to my list of reasons why I don't use Chrome

Comment: you haven't really answered my  question.. I asked `if there is some website whose text field has the sane name, then is there a way to find out what that website is? `   And as to your speculation about what the field may be called, there is no need to, you can look at the inspector for that textbox, it's `name="user_name"`  And I already said in my question about the possibility of 2 sites having the same name. I asked how one can see which sites use that name.